# At a node the wave function

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction

At a node the wave function

a. Passes through 0

b. Becomes 0

Which of the following is right? And most importantly why?

See i have seen the graphs and i can see their that it passes through 0 but why cant it become 0?

Also why cant we explain existence of node by assuming particle nature of atom?

Comment: What about : at a node the wave function _is_ zero.

Comment: Not clear what you are asking. What is the difference between "passes through zero" and "becomes zero"? Where have you read that we cannot explain the existence of a node by assuming the particle nature of the atom? A node is a property of a wave, not a particle. See J Murray's comment below.

Comment: There is a difference which I told in another comment. Yes definitely node is a property of wave but if we were assuming Bohr's model, then how can we discard the idea of node in an atom, that was my question. Anyway it's clear now.

Answer (score 1):

Passing through zero and becoming zero are the same things, just said in different ways. The crucial thing to note is that the probability associated the w.f is zero at a node. That signifies that the probability to occupy the state described by the node is zero.

Edit: Note the comment made by J. Murray

Comment: Note that the probability of finding a particle at *any* individual point is zero, so this is not unique to a node.

Comment: No I believe they are 2 different things, passing through zero means the probability at 0+ and 0- are finite but becoming 0 means that at both the points it's 0 only which is not the case with node that's y we don't consider infinity a node